# Laravel multilevel routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

I have a problem with laravel routing:
When i use single level uri, everything is correct:

```
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```

But when i want to route two or three level uri, It shows the page like there is no CSS but in The page source the CSS assets loads correctly:

```
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostController@create');
```

[load a raw page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1fBP.jpg)

I have this same problem when i use `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould use absolute paths instead of relative ones. [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) helper will help you with building correct URLs for CSS, JS and images:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```